# Optimizing this seemingly slow Query

Tags: optimization, sql

```
        SELECT BR.IDObject AS IDObject,
               B.imgName AS imgName, 
               BK.imgPath AS imgPath,
               BR.imgType AS imgType

        FROM ImageReferences BR
        INNER JOIN BDB_WebImages B ON BR.IDWebImage = B.ID
        INNER JOIN BDB_WebImageCategory BK ON BR.IDImageCategory = BK.ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN DB_IMAGES BDB ON BDB.IDImage = b.IDOriginalBild     

        LEFT OUTER JOIN Multilingual_Translation MLSignature1 ON MLSignature1.IDObject = BR.ID 
                         AND MLSignature1.IDObjectType = 36
                         AND MLSignature1.IDMultilingualAttribute = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Multilingual_Attribute WHERE Tablename = 'BDB_WebImageReference' AND Columnname = 'titel')
                         AND MLSignature1.IDLanguage = 1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Multilingual_Translation MLSignature2
                       ON MLSignature2.IDObject = BR.ID 
                         AND MLSignature2.IDObjectType = 36
                         AND MLSignature2.IDMultilingualAttribute = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Multilingual_Attribute WHERE Tablename = 'BDB_WebImageReference' AND Columnname = 'Description')
                         AND MLSignature2.IDLanguage = 1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Multilingual_Translation MLSignature3
                       ON MLSignature3.IDObject = BR.ID 
                         AND MLSignature3.IDObjectType = 36
                         AND MLSignature3.IDMultilingualAttribute = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Multilingual_Attribute WHERE Tablename = 'BDB_WebImageReference' AND Columnname = 'Signature3')
                         AND MLSignature3.IDLanguage = 1
         LEFT OUTER JOIN SEO_Permalink SEODataWebImage
                ON SEODataWebImage.IDObjekt = BR.ID
               AND SEODataWebImage.IDType = 36
               AND SEODataWebImage.IDLanguage = 1

       LEFT OUTER JOIN SEO_Permalink SEODataBild
                ON SEODataBild.IDObjekt = BDB.IDImage
               AND SEODataBild.IDType = 33
               AND SEODataBild.IDLanguage = 1

WHERE BR.IDObjekt IN (25,26,38,40,45)

AND BR.IDObjectType = 36
```

Comment: what SQL database are you using?

Comment: also please give a little bit more about what you are asking about and what you think is bogging down the query

Answer (score 6):

This query is horribly over-working. I can only believe that the query has been 'simplified' to put here on CR. Otherwise, as far as I can tell, the query can be rewritten as:

```
    SELECT BR.IDObject AS IDObject,
           B.imgName AS imgName, 
           BK.imgPath AS imgPath,
           BR.imgType AS imgType

    FROM ImageReferences BR
    INNER JOIN BDB_WebImages B ON BR.IDWebImage = B.ID
    INNER JOIN BDB_WebImageCategory BK ON BR.IDImageCategory = BK.ID
    WHERE BR.IDObjekt IN (25,26,38,40,45)
     AND BR.IDObjectType = 36
```

This is because all the other tables were `OUTER` joins, and their values are never 'selected' or used for 'projection'. Thus, they were just redundant ....

Comment: what about the `IDMultilingualAttribute`?  that is different in each of those joins.  you gotta scroll all the way over

Comment: Yeah, so? what if it is different. If it matches a record, where is that record **used** (it's not selected anywhere). If it does not match a record, then it's an outer join, so no problem.

Comment: @Malachi - put a different way, where are the table aliases `MLSignature[123]` actually used? **nowhere** !

Comment: I get what you are saying, I see it now.  Forest, trees, running, look at grass, hit tree

Comment: The original query would likely have returned the result set that this simpler query yields, but with each row possibly repeated. Therefore, this query is not identical to the original — it's probably better, assuming you only want distinct rows.

Answer (score 3):

Queries involving a large amount of data blobs on a SQL Server version that does not support streams will be pretty slow.

Try using a common table expression to build up your reference query before hitting the actual image data (I'm assuming you're using data blobs to store your image data - which should be as far down the query as possible).

Also use variables, or more CTE's, to hit your `Multilingual_Attribute` table.

If you're using an environment where CTEs are not available, you can use temp tables and index on `IDWebImage`, `IDImageCategory`, and `IDImage`.

Answer (score 1):

The part of your query where you have several `AND` conditions on your joins is a bit messy, I would put those into your where statement, as it would be cleaner.

You should only join tables **`ON`** their Key columns and not **`ON`** other columns,  it slows down your query because these other columns aren't indexed like a Primary or Foreign key.

You should also use Temp Tables, so that you don't have to call a `SELECT` inside of the table joining on the main query.  This will also make the query faster because you can add indexes and keys where you need to in the temp table.